# Angular 6 - get element from dynamically compiled html

Tags: angular, typescript, p3x-angular-compile

I have HTML string returned from an external API call. I want to compile that HTML string and get a compiled htmlElement by id 'test-input'. I keep getting null or undefined when getting an element from DOM. I am using the library for the [p3x-angular-compile plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p3x-angular-compile):

I used ElementRef and tried querySelector on the `nativeElement`. Still getting null.

```
this.template = '<div id="test-input"><input type="text"></div>';
```

What's expected is that once this template is rendered and compiled, I need the element in order to continue with other manipulation.

Comment: `<span>
<!--- Required -->
 [p3x-compile]="template"
 
 <!--- Required -->
 [p3x-compile-ctx]="this"
</span>`

This is required in your html template as described in the docs of p3x-angular-compile.
Do have something like this in your html template?

Comment: @LittleGnome Yes, i forgot to include that in my code snippet. I have this in my html template:

<div [p3x-compile]="template" [p3x-compile-ctx]="this" [p3x-compile-module]="dataMaterialModule"></div>

Comment: You also tried to wait a tick before retrieving the element via an querySelector?

`// code
setTimeout(() => {});
document.querySelector('id or className');`

It is possible that the DOM isn't updated in an instant, and that the taskqueManager need a tick to update the DOM.

Comment: @LittleGnome Thank you for your response. It's much appreciated. However, I was trying to look for a solution that would not require the use of timeouts in my logic. If all else fails, I will probably use a timeout.